# how to update records else insert records in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

How to perform update and insert in same query? i need to update the record, if it is not present then it has to perform insertion i tried this

```
UPDATE bank SET  Address= $2,"PANCard"= $3,"IFSC" = $4  WHERE user_id = $1;
INSERT INTO bank (user_id,bank_details,"PAN",bank_acc,"UAN",tax)
       SELECT  '$2','$3','$4','$5','$6'
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM bank WHERE user_id=$1);
```

but am getting

```
{
  "name": "error",
  "length": 123,
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "code": "42601",
  "file": "postgres.c",
  "line": "1274",
  "routine": "exec_parse_message"
}
```

please help me here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the UPSERT:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html

Example from documentation:

```
INSERT INTO distributors (did, dname)
VALUES (5, 'Gizmo Transglobal'), (6, 'Associated Computing, Inc')
ON CONFLICT (did) DO UPDATE SET dname = EXCLUDED.dname;
```

Comment: i need to update the row, if the row does not exist then it should insert new one but with the above query new rows are inserted even if is already present. :(

Comment: i gone through the doc, as per the doc `unique index` is required but in my query m using `user_id` as reference it is not unique, if the details is present for this user then it has to do update operation else insert

Answer (score 3):

Error code 42601 [is "syntax_error"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/errcodes-appendix.html), that's the first clue.

You are inserting into 6 columns: `user_id,bank_details,"PAN",bank_acc,"UAN",tax`, but your SELECT clause has only 5 columns: `'$2','$3','$4','$5','$6'`.

I suggest you try your SQL in `psql` or some other tool that give more helpful error messages:

> ```
> create table foo(a int, b int);
> ```

> ```
> insert into foo(a,b) values(1);
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  INSERT has more target columns than expressions
> LINE 1: insert into foo(a,b) values(1);
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=23ad4c63853fcfbc65ceaf8bf0ab51a9)*

Comment: i have added one more column to my select clause by still no use, does version plays a major role in this query ? am using version 9.6

Comment: "still no use" is not an error message. Once you've fixed the syntax, as you are on 9.6, use UPSERT as suggested by @user_0.

Comment: yep i tried UPSERT am getting {
  "name": "error",
  "length": 148,
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "code": "42P10",
  "file": "plancat.c",
  "line": "771",
  "routine": "infer_arbiter_indexes"
}

Comment: @Schüler search for the error code here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/errcodes-appendix.html And then try to fix it yourself.